# what does this css do: ~"-moz-calc(..)"

Tags: css, css-calc

I just noticed a css rule that looked like this

```
width: ~"-moz-calc(100% - 10px)";
```

Now I know -moz-calc, but why is this a string and what is the meaning of the '~'?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Are you sure that isn't LESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually LESS, a CSS preprocessor.

The `~""` syntax creates a [literal value](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping) which doesn't process its contents as LESS.
Otherwise, it would try to compile `-moz-calc()` as a LESS function.